# How do I stop a monthly charge of $5.04 from APL*ITUNES I don't want?

Tags: itunes-store

I have a monthly charge of $5.04 from APL*ITUNES for what, I don't know. I want it stopped.

What can I do to find out what it is for and ultimately how to stop the recurring charge?

Comment: I upvoted this question—while short and broad, it doesn't strike me as inappropriate. What are some possible causes of such a charge, and where can the asker look to investigate? Does iOS et al keep a list of all currently active subscriptions anywhere?

Comment: Apple emails receipts to the email address on file. Check spam filters or junk mail. The receipt may have details.

Comment: Have you seen https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201382

Answer (score 3):

As it is a monthly charge and the same charge every month it is probably a subscription

To view and cancel your subscriptions on a Mac:

> 1. Open iTunes on your Mac.
> 2. Go to the Store section of your Music library.
> 3. Click on the Accounts link in the right column.
> 4. Sign in, if necessary
> 5. Scroll down to the Settings header and click  Manage next to
>      Subscriptions.

([source](https://www.imore.com/how-to-cancel-app-store-subscription-ipad-iphone-mac-apple-tv))

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing to do is check your iTunes purchase history.

1. Open iTunes
2. Click "Store"
3. Review purchases/subscriptions
4. Select Time frame (if applicable)

[image: iTunes Purchase History]

Since it's a recurring charge, there will be a subscription attached to it.  Just cancel the subscription.

If you can't find the charge:

- double check the AppleID/iTunes account used
- [contact Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/)